# How to set value for additional column in pivot table in OctoberCMS?

Tags: relationship, octobercms

I have `doctor` and `specialization` table, and have `doctor_specialization_pivot` table. In my pivot table I have the following columns:

`| doctor_id | additional_data | specialization_id |`

`additional_data` is from the `doctor` model along with the `doctor_id`.

In my `doctor` model file, I have this relationship:

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'specialization' => [
        'path\to\specialization\model', 
        'table' => 'doctor_specialization_pivot', 
        'parentKey' => 'doctor_id', 
        'otherKey' => 'specialization_id',
    ]
];
```

Now during submit of form, I'm getting this error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'additional_data' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into doctor_specialization_pivot (doctor_id, specializations_id) values (1, 3))"`

I tried adding to my relationship `'pivot' => ['additional_data']`. But still getting the same error.

I checked the submitted data and `additional_data` is not empty. I checked from OctoberCMS forums but not getting straight forward answers such as [this](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/setting-pivot-table-default-data) and [this](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/problem-with-october-want-to-save-to-pivot-table-instead-of-model-table).

Comment: Can you mention how you are saving this data? In a frontend form or backend end controller form?

Comment: Also can you show us what you mean the "additional_data is not empty"??

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I found the answer to my own question.

I'll answer in detail to help everyone. After digging and blind shooting. According to this documentation [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#inserting-many-to-many-relations), we can use the method `attach()` *to attach a role to a user by inserting a record in the intermediate table that joins the models*.

What confuse me in the documentation is that it uses a `$roleId` variable and I didn't understand where the `$roleId` came from. If it's the `id` of the parent table or the `id` of other table.

Sample from the link:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

So what I did in my `doctor` model, I hook to the event `beforeSave`, use the relationship  (`$this->specialization`) as the first parameter instead of the `id` in the docs. The `$this->specialization()` is the relationship too defined in `belongsToMany`.

**Answer:**

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->specialization()->attach($this->specialization,['additional_data' => 'additional data from doctor table']);
}
```

Comment: The `$roleId` is the id number of the record (in this example the Roles model) you want to attach to the parent model. So you can do `$role->users()->attach($userId)` in reverse. Hypothetically.

Are you saving this in the backend? Or do you have a front end from and using the php code or a component function? This is never explained in your question and both would have a different answer.

Comment: I'm using a BuilderPlugin for this so I have not change anything about saving, it's just the default of octobercms. I have an issue though with my answer. When I update my form and changed the value of the `specialty_id` from the form. Instead of updating the pivot table record, it inserts a new record perhaps due to `attach()` method. So I'm looking for a different answer perhaps someone could.

Comment: So you are saving the records in the backend like `example.com/backend/plugin/model/create|update` . Yeah I am working on an answer for you in between work. Need to look at my notes.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is pretty much like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssU7JdS3TII) from Watch Learn (Ivan). You can learn a lot about OctoberCMS just by watching his guide on it. Here is the [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#belongs-to-many-pivot) on it as well. This is the example info that I have done.

**WARNING** Another known flaw is you can't apply this to a model record that isn't created yet. Unlike the standard relation widget which waits until it is saved before attaching records this attaches records in a separate overlay form.

Here is my `model.php` relationship:

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'equipments' => [
        'Brandon\Pixelrpg\Models\Equipments',
        'table' => 'brandon_pixelrpg_equipment_inventory',
        'key' => 'inventory',
        'otherKey' => 'equipment',
        'pivot' => ['quantity']
    ]
];
```

Here is my `controller.php`:

```
public $implement = [        
    'Backend\Behaviors\ListController',
    'Backend\Behaviors\FormController',
    'Backend\Behaviors\ReorderController',
    'Backend\Behaviors\RelationController'
];

public $listConfig = 'config_list.yaml';
public $formConfig = 'config_form.yaml';
public $reorderConfig = 'config_reorder.yaml';
public $relationConfig = 'config_relation.yaml';
```

Here is my `config_relation.yaml`:

```
equipments:
    label: Equipments
    view:
        list:
            columns:
                id:
                    label: ID
                    type: number
                    searchable: true
                    sortable: true
                name:
                    label: Name
                    type: text
                    searchable: true
                    sortable: true
                value:
                    label: Value
                    type: number
                    searchable: true
                    sortable: true
                updated_at:
                    label: Updated
                    type: datetime
                    searchable: true
                    sortable: true
                pivot[quantity]:
                    label: Quantity
                    type: number

    pivot:
        form:
            fields:
                pivot[quantity]:
                    label: Quantity
                    type: number
                    default: 0
```

Comment: I watched the video and it's very helpful. But I think the link was more on about managing/displaying the relation in the backend. My problem is that when the user submit a form, I want to save additional value from the form to the the relation table in the database. The answer I had, solved the adding but got to work on in that issue of updating. We have similar problem with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241697/octobercms-update-a-field-in-a-related-table-when-inserting which doesnt have answer yet too.

Comment: I'm checking the event [beforeAttach](https://octobercms.com/docs/api/model/relation/beforeattach) in the documentation but I couldn't find a way to modify the attributes (or add `['additional_data' => 'my data'] `before saving it to the database..

Comment: I asked you if you are using the backend to submit this information. You need show how the users are submitting the form, like the php code you are using. Your question is lacking information now.

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to make a new answer and assume is what you need because you have yet to show any code on how your form works. This is how I would update the pivot information from a frontend form.

Relationship in `model.php`:

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'specialization' => [
        'path\to\specialization\model', 
        'table' => 'doctor_specialization_pivot', 
        'parentKey' => 'doctor_id', 
        'otherKey' => 'specialization_id',
        'pivot' => ['additional_data'] //This is required
    ]
];
```

Then in some php code lets call it `onAddSpecialization()`:

```
public function onAddSpecialization() {
    //Calling a function to get the doctor id maybe from the signed in user
    $doctor = Doctors::find($this->$doctorId());

    //We get our Specialization from an input
    $specialization = Specialization::find(Input::get('specialization_id'));

    //We get our additional data from an input
    $additional_data = Input::get('additional_data');

    //Now we are going to attach the information
    $doctor->specialization()->attach($specialization, ['additional_data' => $additional_data]);
}
```

Now an example of updating our additional data:

```
public function onUpdateAdditionalData() {
    //Calling a function to get the doctor id maybe from the signed in user
    $doctor = Doctors::find($this->$doctorId());

    //If you get specialization by id from an input. I believe you need to go through the relationship in order to access the correct pivot information.
    $specialization = $doctor->specialization->where('id', Input::get('specialization_id'))->first();

    //Insert the new pivot information
    $specialization->pivot->additional_data = $new_additional_data;

    //Save
    $specialization->pivot->save();
}
```